# ContentEditable doesn't work properly with React State (writes in the opposite way)

Tags: reactjs

So, I'm trying to work on an input using contentEditable, but the React State is not working correctly, it writes in oppoiste direction, I already spent a lot time on this, so I thought okay the community could help me on this.

Here is the component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("start");

  return (
    <div>
      Demo: {input}
      <p onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.textContent)} contentEditable="true">
        {input}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-field-5ml5h6

I tried to do something with rtl, but even worse.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the value of it i would like to use ref and then via that ref you have access to the element:

```
const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
<p contentEditable ref={inputRef}>
.....
```

then you can get the value by calling **inputRef.current.innerHTML**:

```
console.log(inputRef.current.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Can you do a working demo, how that fixes the problem I have now?